# python while loop does not show correct output?

Tags: python

**This is quite strange, I am quite sure that the code works without the while loop:**

```
target = [[1],]
add = [2,4]
count = 0

while count < 2:
    temp = []
    for i in target:
        temp += [i, i]
    target = temp[:]

    print('before', target)

    idx = 0
    while idx < len(target):
        target[idx].append(add[idx])
        idx += 1

    print('after', target)        

    add += add      
    count += 1
```

Here I have `target` as a nested list that contains number, I have `add` just as a list of numbers. My idea is to double the `target` every loop, and add one item from `add` to one sub-list of `target` and double the `add` afterwards.

I am getting the result:

```
before [[1], [1]]
after  [[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4]]
before [[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4]]
after  [[1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4]]
```

if you look at the before and after, the whole `add` was added to each sub-list of `target`, instead of adding `add[0]` to `target[0]`, then `add[1]` to `target[1]` showed below as my expectation:

```
before [[1], [1]]
after  [[1, 2], [1, 4]]
before [[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 2], [1, 4]]
after  [[1, 2, 2], [1, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2], [1, 4, 4]]
```

without the outer while loop:

```
target = [[1],[1]]
add = [2,4]
count = 0

idx = 0
while idx < len(target):
    target[idx].append(add[idx])
    idx += 1

print(target)

# >>> 
[[1, 2], [1, 4]]
```

**Can't really understand why**

Comment: Might be because `target = temp[:]` creates only a shallow copy. Try `from copy import deepcopy` and `target = deepcopy(temp)`.

Comment: @Graipher Just tried it, it doesn't work. Still the same output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this block of code:

```
temp = []
for i in target:
    temp += [i, i]
target = temp[:]
```

When it loops over `target`, it pulls out each item, in this case a list (`[1]`). This specific list (not copies) is then added twice to the `temp` list. What you need to do is copy when building temp:

```
temp = []
for i in target:
    temp += [i[:], i[:]]
target = temp
```